# R Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r

I'm really new to this platform and also a very new R user (pls forgive me for not knowing all the terms/slang!). I really need help with this error that I'm receiving when I'm trying to perform a **Bonferroni correction on my ****Chi Square Test**. For context, the data set that I am using is a 2x3 contingency table, looking at the frequency of individuals with a history of smoking, and their development of lung disease (of varying degrees) - since the data I'm working with is not numeric, I can see why this error is popping up everytime I try to run the p-value adjustment. I am also aware that the data available has a frequency of less than 5 for one of the variables I'm looking at, however, for the purposes of this test I believe it is okay to use the aforementioned test as the combination of participants for that cohort is greater than 5. The variable '0' means no smoking, and variable '1' delineates a patient with a smoking habit.

```
Smoking <- table(Smoking$smoke, Smoking$severity)
Smoking <- data.frame(Mild=c(158,637), Mode=c(7,26), Seve=c(3,12), row.names=c("0", "1"))
chisq.test(Smoking)

#Pearson's Chi-squared test

#data:  Smoking
#X-squared = 0.035591, df = 2, p-value = 0.9824

#Warning message:
#In chisq.test(Smoking) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
 

chisq.test(Smoking)$expected
#      Acut      Mild      None
#0 158.4342  6.576512  2.989324
#1 636.5658 26.423488 12.010676
#Warning message:
#In chisq.test(Smoking) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
 
 
chisq.test(Smoking, simulate.p.value = TRUE)$expected
#      Acut      Mild      None
#0 158.4342  6.576512  2.989324
#1 636.5658 26.423488 12.010676

chisq.test(Smoking, simulate.p.value = TRUE)

#   Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates)

#data:  Smoking
#X-squared = 0.035591, df = NA, p-value = 1

p.adjust(Smoking, method="bonferroni")
Error in p.adjust(Smoking, method = "bonferroni") : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

How can I tackle this error?

Thank you so much!!!

I've tried to use `str(x)`, however this method was a little weird and didn't give me the output I was looking for (it's a method I saw someone suggested on here). I have also tried `p.adjust(as.matrix(x), method = x)` and still did not go anywhere with the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO, dodobird99! [1/n] Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (which you have here, thanks!), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(Smoking)` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings ... which you supplied here, again nice!) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: [2/2] The Stack tag-recommendation is imperfect, so please check them all before posting the question. In this case, there is no apparent relevance to the [tag:javascript], [tag:python], [tag:c#], or [tag:php] tags: if you are looking for an implementation in any of those candidate languages, I think you need to be explicit else many think you're tag-spamming. Based on reading the question, none of them seem justified. I'm editing them out for now; if I'm wrong, my apologies, we can rollback my edit fairly easily. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @r2evans, thanks so much for the suggestions!! I'll go ahead and edit my question/description based on your recommendations, and also many thanks for removing irrelevant tags; hopefully i can get the help I need soon!

Comment: hey dodobird99! I just had a read through the documentation of p.adjust. It says that the first input to it should be "a numeric vector of p-values (possibly with NAs). Any other R object is coerced by as.numeric."

Comment: the issue you are facing is that a dataframe is not a vector of numbers, it's a dataframe

Comment: Hi @Mark, thank you so much for your response!! I guess with a set of frequencies I won't be able to perform this test then? I will try and look for other alternatives for correction methods in the meantime.

Comment: I honestly don't know! I'm not familiar with contingency table tests. It seems like the chi squared test produces a p value, so maybe that could be used? (but don't quote me on that)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Value section of `?chisq.test`. It has a list component named “p.value”. You would not have gotten an error with

```
p.adjust(Smoking$p.value)
```

However, the length of that component of Smoking is 1, so p.adjust returns the p.value unchanged. There is no reason to adjust p-value from a single call to `chisq.test`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the underlying question: in most cases, you can dig into your code to discover that the data values you want to feed to  your function (`p.adjust` in this case) are currently stored in a `list` variable.  Depending on your intent,  either  do

`some_func(mylist[[j]])` to grab a single item, or maybe `some_func(unlist(mylist))` to extract all the items.   This depends a lot on how stuff is being stored in your `list` variable.

WARNING:  in some instances, `unlist` can do bad things.  For example, if you try this on a `bigz` object (see package `gmp`), you will most definitely not get what you want.